# Change order of data plotted in ggtile

Tags: r, ggplot2, factors

I'm trying to plot my data in the order specified in the table, but I can't work out how. I think I've managed to change the levels(?) but not the factors(?)

Link to my data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1juBhHNjvsm1otxcpEFu-Zi_v5hSrNj94zdXrENOglTs/edit?usp=sharing

So far I have:

```
BigTree <- read_csv(file = "/cloud/project/Phylogeny/RtreeData.csv")

Bfr <- BigTree[with(BigTree, order(-BfrA, -BfrB, -Bfd, -Ftn, -DPS, 
                                   -Rubrerythrin, -EncFtn, -NEEF)), ]
BfrLong <- pivot_longer(Bfr, 2:9) 
colnames(BfrLong) <- c("Species", "Protein", "Presence")
```

This works to reorder the dataframe and put the data in the order I want to plot it, however I can't plot this dataframe. The error says

> Error in ggplot(BfrLong, aes(x = Protein, y = Species, fill = Presence)) +  :
> non-numeric argument to binary operator

I tried to get the same result using the factor function as below, but it didn't have the desired effect. What am I doing wrong here?

```
BigTreeLong$Protein <- factor(BigTreeLong$Protein, 
                              levels = c("BfrA", "BfrB", "Bfd", "Ftn", "DPS", 
                                            "Rubrerythrin", "EncFtn", "NEEF"))
```

How do I change the factors so the order is maintained during plotting?

My heatmap code so far uses the original BigTree dataframe in long form.
I want to sort it so the top left corner starts with the most light green and it gradually decreases to mostly dark green in the bottom rows.

```
ggplot(BigTreeLong, aes(Protein, Species, fill= Presence)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", linetype = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "darkgreen", high = "olivedrab3") +
  labs(title = "Ferritins present in different bacteria", 
       x = "Ferritin family proteins", 
       y = "Species", 
       fill = "Presence of protein") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, size=8)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle=0, hjust=1, size=6)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("BfrA", "BfrB", "Bfd", "Ftn", "DPS", 
                              "EncFtn", "NEEF", "Rubrerythrin"))
```

This is the heatmap I currently make
[image: gene heatmap current result]

I hope I've included everything I needed to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The levels of your Species column have not been modified in your code, so you will need this line to make it registered :

```
BfrLong$Species=factor(BfrLong$Species,levels=Bfr$Species)
```

Pay attention to the name of your objects in your example, there is BfrLong and BigTreeLong but this should work :

```
BigTree <- read_csv(file = "/cloud/project/Phylogeny/RtreeData.csv")

Bfr <- BigTree[with(BigTree, order(-BfrA, -BfrB, -Bfd, -Ftn, -DPS, 
                                   -Rubrerythrin, -EncFtn, -NEEF)), ]
BfrLong <- pivot_longer(Bfr, 2:9) 
colnames(BfrLong) <- c("Species", "Protein", "Presence")

BfrLong$Species=factor(BfrLong$Species,levels=Bfr$Species)

ggplot(BfrLong, aes(Protein, Species, fill= Presence)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", linetype = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "darkgreen", high = "olivedrab3") +
  labs(title = "Ferritins present in different bacteria", 
       x = "Ferritin family proteins", 
       y = "Species", 
       fill = "Presence of protein") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1, size=8)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle=0, hjust=1, size=6)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("BfrA", "BfrB", "Bfd", "Ftn", "DPS", 
                              "EncFtn", "NEEF", "Rubrerythrin"))
```

[image]